# Allowing FTP with IPTables

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, ftp

My current scenario involves allowing various rules, but I need ftp to be accessible from anywhere.  The OS is Cent 5 and I am using VSFTPD.  I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  All other rules work correctly.

```
## Filter all previous rules
*filter

## Loopback address
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

## Established inbound rule
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

## Management ports
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/24 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/23 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/24 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/23 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/23 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

## Allow NRPE port (Nagios)
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT

##Allow FTP

## Default rules
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

The following are rules I have tried.

```
##Allow FTP
-A INPUT --dport 21 any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT --dport 20 any -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT


-A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d 0/0 --destination-port 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d 0/0 --destination-port 21 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: fixed your formatting so it's readable.

Comment: im assuming you are using Rackspace? the tutorial has that flaw. Just follow @Evan Anderson's instructions.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here's the document I refer people to so that they can following the FTP protocol: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

- To do active-mode FTP, you need to allow incoming connections to TCP port 21 and outgoing connections from port 20.
- To do passive-mode FTP, you need to allow incoming connections to TCP port 21 and incoming connections to a randomly-generated port on the server computer (necessitating using a conntrack module in netfilter)

You don't have anything re: your OUTPUT chain in your post, so I'll include that here, too. If your OUTPUT chain is default-drop then this matters.

Add these rules to your iptables configuration:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -j ACCEPT
```

To support passive mode FTP, then, you need to load the ip_conntrack_ftp module on boot. Uncomment and modify the IPTABLES_MODULES line in the /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config file to read:

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_ftp"
```

Save the iptables config and restart iptables.

```
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

To completely rule out VSFTPD as being a problem, stop VSFTPD, verify that it's not listening on port 21 with a "netstat -a" and then run a :

```
nc -l 21
```

This will start netcat listening on port 21 and will echo input to your shell. From another host, TELNET to port 21 of your server and verify that you get a TCP connection and that you see output in the shell when you type in the TELNET connection.

Finally, bring VSFTPD back up, verify that it is listening on port 21, and try to connect again. If the connection to netcat worked then your iptables rules are fine. If the connection to VSFTPD doesn't work after netcat does then something is wrong w/ your VSFTPD configuration.

Comment: Thank You for the help man, the suggestions you outlined for the passive-mode fixed my issue.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Restarting iptables will wipe out any changes you've made if you don't have IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_STOP set to "yes".

Comment: @Kevin: Absolutely, totally a good point!  >smile<  I'll drop an edit on that now.

Comment: @GLB03: No problem. I live to Server Fault... >smile<

Comment: This answer didn't work for me, so for anyone else having this issue, I'll point out that this (and also opening port 21 input/output) did work for me: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/iptables-rules-for-active-ftp-22127/ -

Comment: Excellent. after hours of thinking my VSFTP.conf was the issue I disabled the the firewall (`sudo service vsftpd stop`) and everything worked..But you can't leave the firewall off ;) Getting the iptable commands for some reason wasn't straight forward with FTP -- this answer was perfect for my situation!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule. Note: `$EXTIP` is your external IP address for the FTP server.

```
-A INPUT -i $EXTIP -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -p TCP -s 0.0.0.0 -d $EXTIP --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing the ip_conntrack_ftp kernel module. It needs to be loaded. So you can try this:

```
modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
```

And also add ip_conntrack_ftp to /etc/modules so it will work after restart