# Enabling VSFTPD through iptables

Tags: iptables, ftp

How do I permit FTP connections on the following IPTables configuration....

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:1111 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered already

[Check This Link](https://serverfault.com/questions/38398/allowing-ftp-with-iptables)

Try

```
 lsmod | grep ftp
 modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
 lsmod | grep ftp
```

1st command should show nothing
3rd command should show something like..

```
ip_conntrack_ftp       41361  0 
ip_conntrack           91621  4 ip_conntrack_ftp,ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat,ip_nat
```

Does this work??

Comment: `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config` does not exist on my system, should I create it?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo doesn't say

Comment: Just try 'modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp', it should load the module.

I believe you can add ip_conntrack_ftp to /etc/modules to get it to load at boot......
Sorry different Linux distributions are a little different :)

Comment: @Arenstar: More recent kernels now call it `nf_conntrack_ftp`, but your advice is still good.

Comment: Neither of those commands returned any result

Comment: Ive updated my response

Comment: Yes, I do see that.  So if I add the command `modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp` it will load that module for FTP and allow me to enter passive mode?  I'm on `Ubuntu` btw

Comment: Yes.. but not through a restart..

You need it to load the module when the server starts up..
So in the file /etc/modules

put it in there..

Comment: Was this succesful???

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks for following up so much, I haven't tested the reboot stuff, I'll do that when it's not mid day