# Enable iptables on one interface

Tags: iptables

I want iptables to filter only one interface, eth0, which is facing WAN. How can this be done? And I want to keep ftp and ssh ports open on eth0.

Comment: Please read the iptables man pages - or in case I misunderstood your problem, please make the question more specific.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

So for all interfaces but one you want to accept all traffic, and on eth0 you want to drop all incoming traffic except ftp and ssh.

First, we could set a policy of accepting all traffic by default.

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Then, we could reset your firewall rules.

```
iptables -F
```

Now we could say that we want to allow incoming traffic on eth0 that is a part of a connection we already allowed.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Also that we want to allow incoming ssh connections on eth0.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

But that anything else incoming on eth0 should be dropped.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```

For slightly more depth see [this CentOS wiki entry](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables).

FTP is a trickier than ssh since it can use a random port, so see [this previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/38398/allowing-ftp-with-iptables).

Comment: WARNING!!! Do "iptables -P..." before "iptables -F". If you're current rules are set to drop traffic by default, running -F will lock you out of your box. This is why keeping the default policy to allow, and to specifically add a rule to drop all other traffic is best practise.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this should do the job:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p all -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p all -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Pretty much spot on (though maybe a bit nicer than "Drop EVERYTHING" on the WAN interface, eh?) -- Write rules to filter the interface you want to filter, and just `ACCEPT` everything on the other interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple when you make an `iptables` rule then you have to specify the interface.
The option to specify the LAN card on which `iptables` should work is `-i`

Following rules can give you a good example

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Last rule is to reject any other packet which does not match the first 2 rules.
All rules in `iptables` are executed in the given order, so the rule to reject packets is always the last.

Answer (score 4):

The option to specify an interface in your iptables rule is `-i`, e.g.: `-i eth0`.