# Linux : FTP connection from server to server not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, debian, ftp

I am working on logging into ftp from our Debian server to another server. It's working from localhost, but not from our server. I have opened ports 21,22 with the following command, but no luck. The -v flag doesn't give any extra verbose input. What am I doing wrong?

Commands :

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d IP --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d IP --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s IP --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s IP --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Log :

```
ftp -v ftp.domain.de
Connected to ftp.domain.de.
220-Welcome To DOMAIN
220 Service ready for new user
Name (ftp.domain.de:root): username
331 Password required
Password:
230 User logged in
Remote system type is MACOS.
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful
150 Opening connection
```

Thank you.

Comment: 22 is usually used for SSH, you might need Port 20 though.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol
usually you can see with packet tracer programms like wireshark or tcpdump from which side the issue is.

Comment: Usually you don't need to have rules for OUTPUT. For INPUT you also need the state tracking RELATED rule. Because active ftp by default opens a connection to the client on a random port that the client chooses. With passive FTP you need the RELATED state on the server.

Comment: @Dennis Nolte : Added the same  commands with port 20 as well. No luck. I will try packet tracer. Anything wrong with the iptables command u can think of?

Comment: have a look at this question, the answers look like they might help you.
https://serverfault.com/questions/38398/allowing-ftp-with-iptables
other than that it might even be a firewall issue on the other end (your client).

for me however it looks like the outgoing connection is not properly "opened" as user188738 commented already.